# How would I use a discord.SelectOption with user input?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a prefix command in my discord bot, to set a custom prefix. I would like to use the new fancy UI objects in the discordpy library. However if I use a `discord.ui.Select` I can only make it so that there are limited options. How would I make it so that one of the `discord.SelectOption` can take user input?

The function would look something like this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def prefix(ctx):
    select = discord.ui.Select(options=[
        # how to get user input here?
        discord.SelectOption(label="Prefix", description="Choose a custom prefix for the bot.")
    ])
    
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(select)
    await ctx.send("Choose an option: ", view=view)
    # prefix then gets saved to a config file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using a Select menu. I recommend that you use a [Modal](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/modals/basic.py) when you need to request an input from the user after executing the command.